# Href and onclick issue in anchor link

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have anchor link with both href and `onclick` events specified. The `onclick` sets `location.href` to server URL and href to a other link.

When the link is clicked the href event gets called always but `onclick` event gets called only once (that is only for one anchor link). If I debug JavaScript it works properly that it calls both href and `onclick`. What can be the problem?

Comment: I think you need more information.  Why are you trying to send two requests with one anchor tag?  What do you mean "gets called only once" -- only for one anchor tag, not all or only the first time, but not after the page is replaced?

Comment: It's completely unclear what your goal is. When you say onclick sets one location, and href - another, which location do you actually want user to go to? You realize he can't go to both locations on one page. By checking comments to some of the answer I get a feeling you want to take user to 1 location and then redirect to another. If yes, then redirect should be issued from server-side. I.e. if you have href="/target.html" and onclick="window.location='/action.call'" you have to put "/action.call" to href, and on server-side send HTTP status 302 redirect. Also, look up "redirect after post"!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
 <a href="whatever.html" onclick='window.location.href="http://whereverelse";return false;'>linky</a>
```

just to explain: returning false in this case prevents the default action.

Why would you want to do this though?

Comment: I guess returning false will stop href functioning.But i want both to work.Onclick does server side work like updating database after which i want to redirect the user to proper link which is specified in href.But this happens only once as stated in the problem.
I tried redirecting the user from server side itself but it fails if url starts with different protocols like mms://, notes:// etc.

Comment: location.href is for changing the current page. It sounds like you want to make an AJAX request

Comment: oh thats so lazy like me... Deuuuude how long you think you can avoid AJAX.. please GIVE IN... i tried the same thing once & i now have... trust me there's peace in submission... lol

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want the link to call a page that runs server-side code (such as PHP) and then direct the browser to another location. That's typically done by having the server-side script send a redirect response with the second URL.

Answer (score 1):

For those who said "Why?", I have a reason.  Middle clicks.  Maybe you have AJAX that can get the details from the server and then prepare them in the same page, but if a middle-clicker wants to see that data in a new page, they are blocked.

So, Reports would provide the same functionality to users who want such a thing.

As a habitual middle-clicker, I hate  tags with a passion.  but I have found with GreaseMonkey, I can sometimes reassign the javascript href to the onclick, and try to parse a valid URL for the href.  I really wish that opening Javascript in a new tab would just clone the page then run the code.