# AJAX GET race condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, race-condition

I am attempting to track events when links are clicked on my site in a method similar to the following.

```
<a href="/example" class="track">Example</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        // track clicks on all anchor tags that require it
        $('a.track').live('click', function(e) {
            // send an AJAX request to our event tracking URL for the server to track it
            $.get('/events/track', {
                    url: $(this).attr('href'),
                    text: $(this).text()
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem that I'm having is that a new page load interrupts the AJAX request, and so sometimes these events aren't being tracked.  I know Google Analytics has a `_trackPageview` function that can be attached to onclick events though, and this doesn't seem to be an issue for that.  I'm wondering what's different about their call vs. mine that I'm seeing this race condition, and GA isn't.  e.g.:

```
<a href="/example" onclick="javascript:pageTracker._trackPageview('/click/example');">Example</a>
```

Note that I'm not worried about the result of the AJAX request...I simply want it to ping the server with the fact that an event happened.

*(Also, I expect I'll get at least one answer that says to simply track the new page load from the server side, not the client side.  This is not an acceptable answer for this question.  I'm looking for something like how Google Analytics' `trackPageview` function works on the click event of anchor tags regardless of a new page being loaded.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running Google's `trackPageview` method through a proxy like Charles shows that calls to `trackPageview( )` request a pixel from Google's servers with various parameters set, which is how most analytics packages wind up implementing such pieces of functionality (Omniture does the same).

Basically, to get around ansynchronous requests not completing, they have the client request an image and crunch the parameters passed in those requests on the server side.

For your end, you'd need to implement the same thing: write a utility method that requests an image from your server, passing along the information you're interested in via URL parameters (something like /track.gif?page=foo.html&link=Click%20Me&bar=baz); the server would then log those parameters in the database and send back the gif.

After that, it's merely slicing and dicing the data you've collected to generate reports.

Comment: How is this preventing the race condition?  Is the pixel loaded in a non-AJAX fashion?  For example, is it loaded into the page in an image tag via `document.write`?  Or is the Javascript Image() object used similar to how preloading images for rollovers used to be done back in the day?  I just want to make sure I implement this correctly such that I don't have the same race condition occurring in a new way.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, essentially the work is all being done on the server side. The client's only responsibility is sending the request; it could insert the image into the page if necessary, but the real action is hitting the server and allowing the server to record what's been sent to it. In this case, you could create a new Image, send an Ajax request, load a script, etc. as long as you're making a request to the server.

Comment: Well that brings me back to my problem in the first place.  I'm making an AJAX get request, but sometimes it's not making it to the server before the requested page on the anchor tag is being loaded.  How can I ensure the image loading won't have the same problem?

Comment: I tried to dig through the GA code, and it looks like their using the Javascript `Image` object.  i.e.: `var image = new Image(1,1); image.src="tracking_pixel_url.gif";`

Comment: The image loading on the client isn't really doing anything here; rather, it's the request to the server that does all the magic.

Answer (score 1):

Matt,

If you just want to make sure that the tracking pixel request is made and you don't depend upon response then just doing document.write for the tracking pixel image will do the work.

And you can do the document.write in your onclick handler.

AFA race condition between href and onclick handler of anchor element is concerned the order is well defined.

the event handler script is executed first
the default action takes place afterwards (in this case the default handler is href)
(Source : [Href and onclick issue in anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964534/href-and-onclick-issue-in-anchor-link))

But yes, if you depend upon the response of the tracking request to the server then you will have to make it synchronous.

Suggested option would be to call some javascript function to wrap the already defined onclick handlers and then in the order make the calls. Make sure that your tracking request is not asynchronous.

Though it is suggested that you should not be dependent upon the response of the tracking pixel request.